# what numbers instead of zero can i use at `Animated.ValueXY(100, 100);`

Tags: reactjs, react-native

when I use `100` as initial values for `ValueXY` at new `Animated.ValueXY(100, 100);` i get this error

```
Error: AnimatedValueXY must be initalized with an object of numbers or AnimatedValues.
```

but when i set them to 0 they or just pass nothing it works fine.

Comment: can you try `Animated.ValueXY({x:100, y: 100})`

Comment: @bennygenel  hmmm it worked!! by why, when i use `Animated.ValueXY(0 ,0);` it works but for other numbers i have to put that `x:` and `y:` please post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Animated.ValueXY(..)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#valuexy) expects an object of numbers or [AnimatedValues](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#animatedvalue) like the error says. To use different values then 0 you need to give them as an object.

```
Animated.ValueXY({x:100, y: 100})
```

When you use `Animated.ValueXY(0 ,0)` it might be taking 0 as a `falsey` and using the default values like you initiated it like `Animated.ValueXY()`. This is just a guess though. Maybe someone with more info can give it a better explanation.